# is it possible to manually assign the value of the dummy variable?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set for automotive sales and i want to change the feature 'aspiration' which contains two unique values 'std' & 'turbo' to categorical values using pd.get_dummies. using the code below;

`dummy_variable_2 = pd.get_dummies(df['aspiration'])`

It is automatically assigning 0 to 'std' &  1 to 'turbo'.

I would like to change to 'std' to 1 & 'turbo' to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return of pd.get_dummmies is a dataframe, which contains one column for each unique value in the dataframe. Whereby, in each column only the values of the corresponding unique value are set to one.

In your case, the dataframe contains two columns. One column is named turbo and one column std. If you want the column where the values of std are set to one, you have to do following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"aspiration":["std", "turbo", "std", "std", "std", "turbo"]}) 
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df)
std= dummies["aspiration_std"]
```

In this example, the variable dummy looks like:

```
   std  turbo
0    1      0
1    0      1
2    1      0
3    1      0
4    1      0
5    0      1
```

and std looks like:

```
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    0
```

Comment: Dear BenHeid, thanks for your answer, but still the get_dummies is assigning 1 to 'std' & 0 to 'turbo'.

Comment: Dear Mohammed, with dummies["aspiration_std"], the lines where aspiration is "std" is one and "turbo" is zero. If you want it the other way round, then try it with dummies["aspiration_turbo"] then "turbo" is one and "std" is zero.